# detect when button is pressed down and then up Swift macOS

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I'm writing an app that send commands to a set top box.
The box can receive two types of commands: push and release.

I can get the button pressed on macOs in swift.
@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: NSButton) { } in which i send the command and the release. For any command such as change channel, mute or other, all works fine.
Instead, for volume up or done, I need, by doing what I do, to click several time to have the volume up or down.

I got the mouse up and down working, detecting where the click happened (inside the NSImageView (if not a button) corresponding to the up and down images) to simulate a long volume up or down press, but I can't get it inside the button pressed method.

is there a way in the 'buttonpressed' method to combine the mouse event in order to simulate a long press while holding the mouse down?

PS: I have googled and searched here also but did not find a hint.

Comment: See [isContinuous](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428952-iscontinuous).

Comment: Hi @10Rep. I tried to get the button pushed through IBAction. I tried to get the mouse events (up or down): working outside of the button, but when the button is pressed, those events do not fire. I tried to avoid using the IBAction and detect if the click has occurred inside the NSImageView (replacing the NSButton) and I get what I want. But I'd like to keep on using the Button and have the logic inside the IBAction, but I do not know how to do. I read the Apple docs about mouse event and button. I'm deeply sorry if I'm not as a good dev as you might be.

Comment: @pm200107 Don't worry. I'm a pretty bad dev myself. Your question is now much better. Just include all the details in the question and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi @Willeke. Thanks for the hint. I read this already and tried without success. I might setup the IBAction wrongly, but basically, when I click the button and keep the mousedown, nothing happens and the IBAction is not fired. When I release the click, then the IBAction fires and isContinuous is false. I'm used to iOS, not macOS. I was looking for a method (or a setup) that detect the click as soon as it arrives (firing thus the IBAction on the click, not on the click release). Does it make sense?

Comment: Did you turn on "Continous" in the storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it can help:

1 subclass the button class to fire the action on mouseDown and mouseUp (the action will be fired twice)

```
 class myButton: NSButton {
     override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()
    let maskUp = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseUp.rawValue
    let maskDown = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown.rawValue
    let mask = Int( maskUp | maskDown ) // cast from UInt
    //shortest way for the above:
    //let mask = NSEvent.EventTypeMask(arrayLiteral: [.leftMouseUp, .leftMouseDown]).rawValue
    self.sendAction(on: NSEvent.EventTypeMask(rawValue: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.RawValue(mask)))
    //objC gives: [self.button sendActionOn: NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask];
}
```

}

2: in the storyboard, change the class of the NSButton to your class:

[image]

3: set the sender of the action to your subclass and check the currentEvent type:

```
@IBAction func volUpPressed(sender: myButton) {
    let currEvent = NSApp.currentEvent
    
    if(currEvent?.type == .leftMouseDown) {
        print("volume Up pressed Down")
        //... do your stuff here on mouseDown
    }
    else
    if(currEvent?.type == .leftMouseUp) {
        print("volume Up pressed Up")
        //... do your stuff here on mouseUp
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your answer? Did you figure it out?

Comment: Then you can accept it as the best answer. Just click the greyed out check button to do so.

Comment: need to wait until tomorrow as per the policy

Comment: for point one: shortest way:let mask = NSEvent.EventTypeMask(arrayLiteral: [.leftMouseUp, .leftMouseDown]).rawValue
        self.sendAction(on: NSEvent.EventTypeMask(rawValue: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.RawValue(mask))) (added to the asnwer as commented code)